# How to modify image field in field_attach_preprocess_alter

Tags: 7, entities

I have an image field called `field_grid_image` on a custom node type "event". I want to populate this field when not available but I don't want to use a default image.
I want to add a default image based on the node's taxonomy. I have written the following code to load the image from node's taxonomy field but it doesn't show up in the final output.

```
function custom_event_field_attach_preprocess_alter(&$variables, $context) {
    if($context['entity_type'] == "node" && $context['entity']->type == "event" && sizeof($context['entity']->field_grid_image) == 0){
        $tid = $context['entity']->field_event_type['und'][0]['tid'];
        $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

        $values = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $taxonomy_term, 'field_generic_image');
        $variables['field_grid_image']['und'][0] = $values[0];

        dpm ($values);
        dpm( $variables);
    }
}
```

When I print $variables I see the field populated from the taxonomy as follows.

[image: <code>dpm($variables)</code> output]

Any ideas why the image is not rendered in the final output?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem. I should have used `field_view_value` to render the field and add it to `$variables['content']` instead of editing the field directly.

The below code works as expected now.

```
function custom_event_field_attach_preprocess_alter(&$variables, $context) {
    if($context['entity_type'] == "node" && $context['entity']->type == "event" && sizeof($context['entity']->field_grid_image) == 0){
        $tid = $context['entity']->field_event_type['und'][0]['tid'];
        $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

        $values = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $taxonomy_term, 'field_generic_image');
        $node = $variables['node'];
        $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_grid_image', $values[0], array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'settings' => array(
            'image_style' => 'gridimage',
            'image_link' => 'content',
            ),
        ));

        $variables['content']['group_image_text']['field_grid_image'] = $output;
    }
}
```